# how do i Add Array list from Json string to an Android listview Xamarin

Tags: android, arrays, listview, xamarin, restsharp

I have the Following Json Data that im pulling from ""http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons/
Here is the code i have so far, i want to add the " items = resp[i].caption();" to the listview and im stuggling since this is my first android project, im used to the windows listitems.add

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<SportsRadio.seasons.RootObject> list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SportsRadio.seasons.RootObject>();
String[] items;

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   var client = new RestClient() { BaseUrl = new Uri("http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons/") };
   var request = new RestRequest() { Resource = "", Method = Method.GET, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

   client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, handle) =>
   {
       RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
       var resp = deserial.Deserialize<List<SportsRadio.seasons.RootObject>>(response);

       string json = response.Content;


    for (int i = 0; i < json.Length; i++)
       {
           items[i] = resp[i].caption;


       }

 ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

       });


namespace SportsRadio.seasons
{
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public string league { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

}

i created the class using Json2Csharp

Comment: You have quite a few easy to spot errors in your code. For example the adapter is not assigned to a listview. Also the adapter being created for each loop in the `for` section instead of after it has finished. I suggest you try creating a "hello world" project with just a simple listView so that you learn the basics and then come back here again with a more concrete question. good luck.

Comment: the Activity is a ListActivity, the adapter does not need to be assigned a Listview... im not using a custom adapter